Lasker Nim Sprague-Grundy Function Proof claims
I have recently been looking into the Lasker Nim proof for its Sprague-Grundy function and have found this psot helpful
Lasker Nim, Sprague-Grundy Function Proof
However I still do not understand why  some of the claims.
If the Sprague grundy function is :
g(x)=
\begin{cases} 
    0 & \text{if } x = 0 \\ 
    4k + 1 & \text{if } x = 4k + 1 \ \forall \ k \geq 0 \\ 
    4k + 2 & \text{if } x = 4k + 2 \ \forall \ k \geq 0 \\ 
    4k + 4 & \text{if } x = 4k + 3  \ \forall \ k \geq 0 \\ 
    4k + 3 & \text{if } x = 4k + 4  \ \forall \ k \geq 0 
\end{cases}
I understand that you can prove by induction on $k$ with the claim it is true for $n < 4k + 1$.
In the 1st case the two pile options are $(4l + 1, 4m)$ and $(4m + 3, 4l +2)$; you can show for each pile the grundy value will be even.
However how do you prove that the value is less than or equal to $4k$ just as it is even? Same goes with the equivalent claims for the other 3 functions? Please could someone help explain this step, especially for $g(4k +3) =4k+4$?
Also how do you prove that there are only those choices of piles to split it to?
